# Mute JWPlayer on iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, jwplayer

I would like to mute on default our JWPlayer. 
Unfortunately it I can't find an appropriate configuration variable for that

```
let configuration: JWConfig = JWConfig(contentURL: playerURL)

... 
configuration.mute = true // No such thing :((
...

let jwPlayer = JWPlayerController(config: configuration)

...

addSubview(jwPlayer.view)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `volume` property of [JWPlayerController](https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/ios/reference/Classes/JWPlayerController.html#//api/name/volume):

```
jwPlayer.volume = 0.0
```

Comment: It does turn down the volume. But I need the mute button to appear (like Android have) when pressing it the volume should appear.

Comment: @Luda: I can see that there is a mute configuration available in the configuration, https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/javascript-api-reference/

Comment: Not seeing the same for iOS though

Comment: I don't see it as well :"(

Comment: Accepted your answer as it helped me even though it wasn't exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Luda If you find a solution to this problem, please don't forget to post as an answer. Happy Coding !!!